# Salesforce System Integrator (SI) Partner & its Cost

Tags: partner

What are requirements (or eligibility criteria) to become a Salesforce System Integrator (SI) Partner? How much does it cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any upfront costs to join the Salesforce Partner program.

You can sign up here:https://partnersignup.salesforce.com/

However partners do have a number of requirements they need to meet to obtain the various levels, which will cost money and time.

For starters, partners need to maintain a certain number of certified individuals (Sales Cloud, Service Cloud, Developer, Advanced Developer, and Technical Architect) to be awarded status levels (http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_ConsultPartnerRequire.pdf). Partners also need to bring in specific revenue requirements (number of licenses, projects, etc).

As a SI you will partner a lot with the Salesforce Account Executives (AE's) to win deals and ensure your clients are happy with your finished implementation.

I have worked for 2 different SFDC Partners and it can be exciting but challenging. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There will be fees for SI partners this year, starting at $1K
http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2015/02/introducing-new-salesforce-partner-program-consulting-partners-.html